# Does Metal Shading Language always assumes 4-component pixel format when reading or writing to textures?

Tags: ios, gpu, textures, gpgpu, metal

I just want to confirm that how I'm working with textures in 1-, 2- or 3-component pixel formats is a right way to do it in [Metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API)).

Let’s assume we have assigned a texture `pixelFormat = .rg32Float` in host code.

Then in [Metal Shading Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API)) (MSL):

```cpp
kernel void test(
    texture1d<float, access::read_write> texture [[texture(0)]],
    ushort tid [[thread_position_in_grid]]
) {
    // Read
    float2 value = texture.read(tid).xy;

    // Write
    texture.write(float4(value.x, value.y, 0, 0), tid);
}
```

Do we really always need to use the per-component getters for reading and wrapping the value (automatically or manually) to `float4` for writing to properly work with less than 4-component pixel formats in MSL?

It's inconvenient. At least it doesn't introduce any overhead I guess, i.e., not actually writing those zeros and taking twice as bandwidth as it should.

Comment: The shader doesn't know and doesn't care what the pixel format is gonna be. You could bind a texture with `.rgba8` format to texture binding point zero and the shader still has to work. So yes, it's always 4 components.

Comment: Does it have any implications on bandwidth? I.e. working with 1-component textures is not more efficient then 4-component then? Or the same shader would only take as much bandwidth as it needs depending on the pixel format at the binding point?

Comment: It seems a lot like out-of-bounds read/writes but at the same time completely different. I guess shader just always translates any texture pixel format to `type4` at read and `type4` to texture pixel format at write. The translation is hardware-accelerated with no additional cost whatsoever. I guess `texture_buffer`'s were specifically introduced to take advantage of this accelerated translation mechanics.

Comment: While you're correct that shaders do not know the exact pixel format, the type used in the shader and the pixel format of the texture must be compatible according to the Metal Shading Language Specification. For instance, using a `.rg32Float` texture with a `texture2d<float, access::read>` resource in your shader is correct. 

When it comes to efficiency and bandwidth, it's important to note that the use of a `float4` type in the shader doesn't mean that four components are always read from and written to memory.

Comment: The hardware is aware of the actual pixel format and will only read/write the necessary components. So in your case, if you're using a `.rg32Float` texture, only the red and green components are read/written. 

Your intuition is right about the translation. The translation between a `float4` in the shader and the actual pixel format in the texture is hardware-accelerated and designed to be extremely efficient. In fact, the GPU's memory subsystem is designed around these 4-component vectors, which is part of why the Metal Shading Language uses them so extensively.

Comment: The hardware will automatically convert between the shader's `float4` and the texture's actual pixel format at no extra cost, ensuring that your shader operates efficiently regardless of the texture's format.

Comment: Regarding texture buffers, their main advantage lies in the fact that they offer raw, unfiltered access to memory. This means you can use them to store data in formats that are not directly supported by traditional textures. However, they don't perform any kind of accelerated translation. They can be seen as more of a general-purpose buffer that you can interpret however you want in your shader, rather than something designed to specifically leverage the 4-component vector hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in your assumption, as per the Metal Shading Language Specification, that you need to operate with 4-component vectors irrespective of the actual pixel format of your texture. This is due to the way the language is defined and structured, rather than a hardware limitation or requirement.

The Metal Shading Language expects a 4-component vector (float4 for example) for reading from and writing to textures. When you use less than a 4-component texture (like .rg32Float), you'll need to adjust your code to use a float4, but only access the components that are applicable (r and g in your example).

Here's the code snippet you provided, slightly adjusted:

```
kernel void test(
    texture1d<float, access::read_write> texture [[texture(0)]],
    ushort tid [[thread_position_in_grid]]
) {
    // read
    float2 value = texture.read(tid).rg;

    // write
    texture.write(float4(value, 0.0, 0.0), tid);
}
```

Note: We're reading the value into a float2, and writing a float4 back to the texture, but the third and fourth components of the float4 are not used and do not consume extra bandwidth, because the hardware understands the actual format of the texture and only writes the necessary components to memory.

Although it might seem a bit verbose to work with 4-component vectors even when the pixel format has fewer components, this convention is necessary due to the design of the Metal Shading Language. However, rest assured that this doesn't imply a performance overhead or unnecessary memory usage. The GPU's hardware is aware of the texture's actual format and only the required components are written to memory, maintaining optimal performance and efficiency.

Comment: ChatGPT-generated (i.e. treat it as likely to be inaccurate)

Comment: test it, David.

Comment: Haha, I see it now. Too smooth wording. But you got me. Are you guys doing this on purpose to raise awareness?

Comment: nah he just doesn't care for me. but go ahead. try it.

Comment: Nothing to try there :)
Although I've tried using ChatGPT for some questions I had some time ago. Surprisingly good especially when you're familiar enough with the topic and can spot complete nonsence yourself. It often still can lead you to better understanding more effective then simple search.

Comment: You're absolutely right. It doesn't look correct to me at all! There's never 4 components when reading and writing. 

Also, you *could* use swizzling to make some widening expressions more compact, like ```texture.write(float4(value, 0.0, 0.0), …)``` could be written ```texture.write(value.rggg, …)``` for example. But don't test that. You might learn something.